# Finding #N/A with InsTr Run-time error 13 (2042) VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I waited and thought it through again, I searched, I tried assigning the search string to a variable, tried 'variant' variable, tried changing the search start position....not working.

I need to loop through a column range and find #N/A to remind the user that something is wrong (w/ one Msgbox). The ACTUAL VALUE is "#N/A" because I'm copying and pasting the resulting formula value over itself.

It DOES work with a single pound sign as the item to be searched for w/ InStr if I find and replace the "#N/A" with just "#" as an exercise (e.g.:

```
 If  InStr(1, Weightval.Value, "#") > 0 Then
```

But doesn't work this way:

```
Dim LastRowNum As Long
Dim Weightval As Range
Dim SearchRange As Range

Set SearchRange = Range("W2:" & "W" & LastRowNum)    
For Each Weightval In SearchRange
            If InStr(1, Weightval.Value, "#N/A") > 0 Then
            MsgBox ("One or more weight value(s) is missing.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Next Weightval
```

FYI Obviously there is some other code in the sub, I'm just taking the part that doesn't work here.

I just know this is going to be something simple and I hate these situations because I'm not experienced enough to figure it out by myself. If someone wants to give me a CLUE that would be great so I can try to figure it out myself.

Comment: The value you are looking for....will it have only "#N/A"? or Will it have something like else other that just "#N/A"..for ex("#N/A KG/LB")

Comment: Just #N/A for now because that's the resulting error from the value not being in the vlookup (as I mentioned, there's a copy -> xlpastevalues so that it just becomes text not a formula. In the future I may change the formula to an ISERROR or IFERROR so I can put something else there.

Comment: Maybe InStr isn't the right thing to use to find the text? I don't know. Why can't it just be if Range(cell number) = "#N/A" ?

Is there a way to use cells.find and return a true false value instead? Just trying to think outside the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **.Text** rather than **.Value**:

```
Sub fjdsrjsgf()
    Dim LastRowNum As Long
    Dim Weightval As Range
    Dim SearchRange As Range

    LastRowNum = 19
    Set SearchRange = Range("W2:" & "W" & LastRowNum)
    For Each Weightval In SearchRange
        If InStr(1, Weightval.Text, "#N/A") > 0 Then
                MsgBox ("One or more weight value(s) is missing.")
                Exit Sub
        End If
    Next Weightval
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If you examine my picture carefully, you will see that I created the `#N/A` by using the formula `=VLOOKUP(0,0,0)` *(as shown in the Formula Bar)*.  This creates a true error.  If I had just typed:

```
'#N/A
```

in the cell, then **.Value** would have worked!

*(Excel VBA can tell the difference between the true error and a text string mimic-ing an error................ **.Value** and a true error do not mix)*

Comment: Can you give me some clues on how I should have been able to figure that out by myself? Like, I would have never known that the variable could have had an extension called text.

Comment: @purplefolder  **It's not your fault.** ............it most cases, using **.Value** will work for any kind of number or text, ***except errors***............for errors, you must use **.Text**

Comment: How does Excel know that's an error when it simply is just text in a cell and not a formula (asume you had copied all those junk & #N/As and pasted special > value? Does Excel assume a true text value of #N/A equals an error no matter what?

Comment: @purplefolder  See my **EDIT#1**..............perhaps it will shed some light on this.

Comment: So, is there a state in which Excel marks a cell value as an error, even though it has been converted to a text value with copy> paste special? I don't know how to post more code in a comment or if it's even possible. 

Because this is what happens earlier, 
    Range("W2:" & "W" & LastRowNum).Value = "=VLOOKUP(C2,'weight table.xlsx'!Weight,2,FALSE)"
            Range("W2:" & "W" & LastRowNum).Copy
            Range("W2:" & "W" & LastRowNum).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: Basically, what I'm saying is that Excel ISN'T telling the difference, because it's being converted to a value from copy> paste special. So I think there's something behind the scenes where a cell is flagged as an error cell even though the value is no longer a formula.

Comment: Try this experiment:  starting with a clean worksheet, simply type `#N/A` in both **A1** and **A2**.  In another cell, enter the formula `=A1=A2`  You will see an error rather than `True`....................Repeat the experiment, but first format both **A1** and **A2** as `Text`.  Now the formula will show `True`......................Using **.Text** in VBA always gets the *what-you-see-is-what-you-get*  value.

Comment: Using **.Text** means never having to worry if the error is real or just a text string.

Comment: I apologize if my ability to explain this is limited.

Comment: I think just as Excel "helpfully" converts something that *looks* like a date into a date when you enter it in a cell, it will do the same thing with "#N/A" (ie. convert it to an Error), unless you explicitly tell it not to by formatting the cell as text (as GS notes)

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way is to use variants and IsError (and/or CVErr if you want to check for a specific error). The reason its better is that using .Text is very slow and error-prone. (see my [article](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/) on .Text vs .Value vs .Value2)

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindError()
    Dim j As Long
    Dim LastRowNum As Long
    Dim Weightval As Variant
    LastRowNum = 21
    Weightval = Range("W2:" & "W" & LastRowNum)
    For j = LBound(Weightval) To UBound(Weightval)
        '
        ' use IsError() to determine if a variant contains an error
        '
        If IsError(Weightval(j, 1)) Then
        '
        ' use cverr to check for a particular error
        '
            If Weightval(j, 1) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
                MsgBox ("One or more weight value(s) is #N/A at row " & j + 1)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! *(and the reference)*.

Answer (score 1):

Use IsError() not search for #N/A in text

```
    Dim LastRowNum As Long
    Dim Weightval As Range
    Dim SearchRange As Range

    Set SearchRange = Range("W2:" & "W" & LastRowNum)
    For Each Weightval In SearchRange
        'If InStr(1, Weightval.Value, "#N/A") > 0 Then
        If IsError(Weightval.Value) Then
            MsgBox ("One or more weight value(s) is missing.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next Weightval
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there a state in which Excel marks a cell value as an error,

`range.specialcells` property can mark the cell with error.

Sorry, I do not have enough reputation to add a comment.